# React Native: Cannot load an empty url (iOS Release Build)

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have an issue with the iOS release build of my React Native app. It actually does load the app, but after I login the app suddenly crashes and XCode shows me the error `Cannot load an empty url` - this happened out of nowhere and the app works fine in the debug build.

I have no idea how to locate the error - any ideas?

```
2018-02-14 23:17:34.632 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] 
Cannot load an empty url
2018-02-14 23:17:34.636284+0100 MyApp[24795:2328074] Cannot 
load an empty url
2018-02-14 23:17:34.638 [fatal]
[tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: 
Cannot load an empty url
```